# regex to extract strings in python list

Tags: python, regex

I have a list that contains addresses. I would like to extract just the street names from them.

Suppose, my strings are as follows:

```
'897 har glen apt. 55'
'47 ts brook suite 93'
```

I want two types of answers :
One that has the following:

```
'897 har glen'
'47 ts brook'
```

The other answer should have just the street names:

```
'har glen'
'ts brook'


m = re.findall('(?:\w+[apt|suite])', '897 har glen apt. 55')
```

The above command doesn't work. I think the second one is easier. But I really would like to know how to go about the first. Essentially, I don't want anything the phrase that starts with "apt" or "suite" in my string.

Regex is too confusing for me and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having wrestled with regex in the past, this tool may be helpful - http://regexr.com/

Comment: how about this? [re.sub('\s*(apt|suite).*$', '', addr) for addr in addrs]

Comment: Where do people get the idea that `[apt|suite]` is the correct way to match alternatives in regex? We see it all the time, yet it can't possibly be in any tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are or could be a bit vague, but something like this might work:

```
\d+[ \t]*(.*?)[ \t]*(?=apt|suite)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ctLgLI/1)

Which for a more complete example with Python looks like this:

```
s = """
897 har glen apt. 55
47 ts brook suite 93
"""

for match in re.findall(r"\d+[ \t]*(.*?)[ \t]*(?=apt|suite)", s):
    print(match)
```

Which outputs:

```
har glen
ts brook
```

Comment: Instead of `[ \t]` use `\s` to match whitepace.

Comment: @Barmar Purposely using `[ \t]` as `\s` also matches newlines, which might not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this.

```
addrs = ['897 har glen apt. 55', '47 ts brook suite 93']
[re.sub('\s*(apt|suite).*$', '', addr) for addr in addrs]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check Live Demo](https://repl.it/HTHu/0)

```
import re
m = re.findall('(.*)([apt|suite].*)', '897 har glen apt. 55')
print([ i for i in m])
```